# “Request desktop site” on iOS still gives me the mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web

As in the title - the “request desktop site” option in Chrome on my iPhone doesn’t do anything anymore. :-(

Example of mobile vs desktop with electronics stack exchange:

[image: elec-mobile]
[image: elec-desktop]

And stack overflow, which is the same no matter which site I request.

[image: so-either]

The menu option in question (I think it changes the browser identifies to the site somehow? I’m not a web programmer, sorry).

[image: Menu]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you're seeing. A bunch of things have changed on our side recently, and I don't normally use Chrome on my iPhone, so I'm not even sure what you're expecting to see vs what's actually happening.

Comment: Added some screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow [recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) switched to a responsive design. There isn't a separate mobile site anymore.

You can confirm this by enabling *Responsive Design Mode* in your desktop browser, see how it looks the same as in the screenshot from your phone:

[image: screenshot of Stack Overflow in responsive design mode]

Comment: So what do I do to make the site useful on my phone again?

Comment: Well, you can give specific feedback on improvements you'd like to see. "make the site useful again" is a bit vague 

Comment: Put all the stuff that was on the homepage back on my phone screen? Hot questions/search bar/etc etc etc. Looks like the new design has been downvoted a  bunch and there are lots of good suggestions over there... I'm not sure what else to say?